# How can I email one of the cronjob lines to a different email address?

Tags: cron

I have the MAILTO setting set in crontab to a certain email address, eg
a@ab.com

There are about 10 entries in the cron on different lines, running at different times and I want to add an 11th line but have it sent to a different email address.

How can I do this from within the crontab?

```
awk 'last ~ "<cert>" && $0 ~ "</cert>" {print FILENAME; nextfile} {last=$0}' *
```

I have tried using an output command but it is only outputting to a file.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a different MAILTO line preceeding your 11th line - that setting will remain in effect for all subsequent cron lines:

```
MAILTO='a@ab.com'
* * * * * /cmd1
# other crontab jobs here, all emailing to 'a@ab.com'
* * * * * /cmd10

MAILTO='someone_else@ab.com'
# following crontab jobs emailing to 'someone_else@ab.com'
* * * * * /cmd11
```